# Tee-off, what is it?

Tags: gear

I've been looking for explanation to this term recently but it's still unclear for me. Is it some sort of bolted connection or the beginning part of a busbar ? I'm asking because I found this in MV switchgear technical materials and there is no description for it.

https://scr.hu/ezYkra
https://scr.hu/GYdgoZ

Comment: It's how you start a round of golf.

Comment: You don't really give us enough context to go from. What technical manual? Where's the link?

Comment: All I have is the temperature value and a name of temperature sensor place like " connection of tee-off and bus-bars in L1 " where L1 is a phase name. The materials are classified so I am not able to stare them :(  There is also mentioned a "connection of pin contact and tee-off in L1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of the usage of the term "tee-off" would indicate that something about the connection is similar to the letter "T." It appears that it refers to a load connection that is made at a point on a bus bar where the bus bar comes from the source in one direction and continues on to other loads in the opposite direction.